# Codename One - tabs.addSelectionListener + tabs.removeTabAt = java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: codenameone

My app adds new tabs when the user taps some buttons. I want that every time that the user swipes from the last tab to the penultimate tab, the last tab should be automatically deleted.

My draft of code:

```
tabs.addSelectionListener((oldSelected, newSelected) -> {
    Log.p("There are " + tabs.getTabCount() + " tabs in total");
    Log.p("Index of oldSelected tab: " + oldSelected);
    Log.p("Index of newSelected tab: " + newSelected);
    if (newSelected == oldSelected - 1) {
        Log.p("The user selected the previous tab");
        tabs.removeTabAt(oldSelected);
        Log.p("I removed the oldSelected tab");
    }
});
```

It generates a `StackOverflowError`, I suppose because there is an infinite recursion caused by `removeTabAt` that does an unnecessary and unrequested selection of the already selected tab (causing an invoking of the `SelectionListener`).

The log:

```
[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - There are 2 tabs in total
[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - Index of oldSelected tab: 1
[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - Index of newSelected tab: 0
[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - The user selected the previous tab
[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - There are 2 tabs in total[EDT] 0:0:10,747 - Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError - null
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying a component as a result of an event within that component which is generally problematic as the event firing code probably relies on the structure of the component.

You can use `callSerially` to defer the mutation of the UI to the next EDT cycle:

```
callSerially(() -> tabs.removeTabAt(oldSelected));
```

Comment: I confirm that your suggestion solves the problem in an easy way, thank you :)